# What country am I travelling from if there's a layover for visa application?

Tags: visas, air-travel, us-citizens, egypt

I'm applying for an Egyptian visa and the website to do so ([Egypt e-Visa Portal](https://visa2egypt.gov.eg)) is asking for the country that I'm traveling from.

So let's say I was a United States citizen that was going to spend a few days in France before flying to Egypt. I assume that I would say that France is the country that I'm traveling from.

What if I was a United States citizen that was doing a layover in France, but I wasn't actually going to be leaving the airport? At that point, would I be flying from France, or would I be flying from the United States?

Comment: I would say the US if you are checked-through. More generally, the last country you went through passport control in.

Comment: @jcaron that sounds like an answer, and it has more depth than the current answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you entered France, then it's France.  If you're in transit you're not technically 'entering' the country, you're just passing through the outside-immigration-zone.  So in the case you stay in Paris a few days - you'd write France. If just stopping in Charles de Gaulle Airport to change planes to fly to Egypt - put the USA.